# Come have a private Little Academia 2 post-premier community watching party with us!

Tags: discussion, community-events

As some may or may not be aware, quite recently at Anime Expo, [*Little Academia 2: The Enchanted Parade*](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1311401276/little-witch-academia-2/description) premiered at AnimeExpo on 07/03/15 @ 8:30p EST!

It's expected that many fans in this community were probably unable to make the convention. Being a Kickstarter backer, I have access to the advanced preview screening stream. Which is why I will offer to host **at least two** private community viewing sessions for the **~53 min OVA episode** before July 11th, via [Rabb.it](https://rabb.it/).

The rooms can have up to 10 users and there can be multiple rooms per session. Please take the time **propose and vote on some stream dates times** (preferably for two different global time zones) to host these sessions. Recording the stream during this session will be prohibited.

Please note that this is a private community event and not affiliated with StackExchange. All are welcomed to participate. The only requirement to attend is that you have an active chat account as invites will be distributed via chat. While this is a non-affiliated community event, StackExchange's [code of conduct](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) will still apply. Any users found in violation may be removed and barred from future events.

You do not have to have watched the previous OVA to watch this one, but it will give you a better appreciation of Sucy's character.

Please note due to this being a broadcast stream, **a connection speed of at least 16 Mbps** (megabits/s, or ~2 MBps [megabytes/s] downstream) is recommended.

[image: It's a fiesta!]

Comment: If a proposed time doesn't work for you, please suggest another one. If at least 2 other ppl was willing to start it at that time slot, I'll host it.

Answer (score 4):

**Date:** 7/4 (Sat.) or 7/5 (Sun.)

**Time:** 1:00 pm EDT (1700 UTC) or 8:00 pm EDT (000 UTC).

Comment: two days, either times.

Comment: Propose. Another time, any time.

Answer (score 0):

I propose 8/7  20:00 UTC , (7/8 for you Americans) simply because I can't watch it before then.

Comment: Gimmie a ping in chat when you want to see it and I'll set one up if I can.