# Proposal: Let's get together and actually watch some anime (related) movies together

Tags: discussion, community-events

The weekends tends bit be a bit slow in chat despite the spikes in traffic we get on Sundays. I thought, why not spend a day on a weekend once a month to watch some anime (related) movies?

Partially in the spirit of our previous [Little Witch Academia premiere screening](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/come-have-a-private-little-academia-2-post-premier-community-watching-party-with), I'd is to introduce people so some of the anime media (that's not TV anime) that you usually don't often get a chance to see. This proposed event also serves are a way for current users to introduce those they know, who also enjoy anime, to our community.

Some potential prospects for watching are:

[*Patema Inverted*](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/patema_inverted/)

[image: Patema Inverted]

> Time of Eve director Yasuhiro Yoshiura is a perspective-twisting sci-fi adventure about two kids separated by opposite gravities. Patema lives in an underground world of tunnels, the long-abandoned ruins of a giant industrial complex. Though she is a princess, she is held back by the rules imposed by the elders of her clan. One day when she is exploring in a forbidden zone, she is startled by a strange bat-like creature and tumbles headlong into a void - and out into the wide open world above the surface, a place with reversed physics, where if she let go she would "fall up" into the sky and be lost forever. Age is a student on this surface world, a totalitarian society whose compliant population has been brainwashed against the "sinners who fell into the sky." When he spies Patema hanging upside-down from a tree, he pulls her down to safety, struggling with all his might to keep her earthbound as she grips on to him for dear life. Together their weights cancel each other out, and once they master the art of navigating competing gravitational forces, they set out to evade the leaders of Age's world and discover the secret that keeps their worlds apart

[*Kingdom of Dreams and Madness*](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_kingdom_of_dreams_and_madness/)

[image: Kingdom of Dreams and Madness]

> A documentary about Hayao Miyazaki's life and Studio Ghibli

[*Letter to Momo*](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/a_letter_to_momo/)

[image: Letter to Momo]

> From the creators of Ghost in the Shell comes a wonderfully expressive and beautifully hand drawn animated tale that combines bursts of whimsy and kinetic humor with deep felt emotion and drama. The last time Momo saw her father they had a fight - and now all she has left to remember him by is an incomplete letter, a blank piece of paper penned with the words "Dear Momo" but nothing more. Moving with her mother to the remote Japanese island of Shio, Momo soon discovers three yokai living in her attic, a trio of mischievous spirit creatures that only she can see and who create mayhem in the tiny seaside community as she tries desperately to keep them hidden. But these funny monsters have a serious side and may hold the key to helping Momo discover what her father had been trying to tell her. A Letter to Momo was seven years in the making, and the handmade animation is superb, from the painstakingly rendered serenity of the island's Shinto shrines to the climactic finale - a frantic chase featuring thousands of squirming, morphing ghosts and spirits that is the best cinematic flight of supernatural fancy in many years.

[*Tatsumi*](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/tatsumi_2011/)

[image: Tatsumi]

> A story based on the life and short stories of Yoshihiro Tatsumi, a mangaka known for his gekiga style of alternate Japanese manga.

**Proposals and suggestions for other movies are welcome as well. Feel free to leave it here.**

I'd like to start using community activities such as this to better develop relations between current users, encourage more active discussion in the realms of anime and manga, and also allow for more opportunities for non-users to get a chance to better know our site and community.

The format would be pretty simple, every first weekend of the month we would have two of these watching session via [Rabb.it](https://rabb.it/). There will be two sessions to accommodate users from different time zones. Users can vote on what to watch beforehand and invite their friends to come watch and, perhaps afterwards, stop by discuss the movie afterwards in our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-). Explicit write permissions will be give to new users who wish to participate, but do not have the necessary 20 rep to talk in chat.

Given the the session is a shared stream, there will be a minimum bandwidth speed requirement for optimal viewing experience. We can do some test sessions before starting to ensure there are no problems with your viewing experience (i.e. lag, dropped, frames).

With all this said and done, would anyone be interested in such as session? IT doesn't have to be a big event with a lot of people. This event primarily for your enjoyment. What do you say? Are you interested?

Comment: This sounds good to me! Having participated in the previous viewing session of *Little Witch Academia*, I think this would be a good idea.

Comment: I approve of all these suggestions